# How to set different gravity for TextInputLayout's hint and text in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, gravity, android-textinputlayout

How to set different gravity for TextInputLayout's hint and text entered in edit text. I want to set the hint gravity to start and edit text's text gravity to center. So how can i achieve this.
This is my xml code,

```
              <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:gravity="start">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
                            android:hint="Email"
                            />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: why you are giving hint in both textInputLayout and Edittext? I think, you should give in edittext only.It work also same.

Comment: ya i have removed

Comment: hint is only for edit text.

Comment: To give, edittext gravity in center please show my below code.

Comment: it is meaning less to show hint on both, but still you want to show than in edit text give             android:textAlignment="center"

Comment: i want to show the hint at top|left and the text typed in edit text to be at center.

Comment: The floating hint's alignment is determined when the `EditText` is added to the `TextInputLayout`, which will happen during inflation, in this case. To set a different gravity for the `EditText`, don't set any `gravity` attributes in the layout, then set the `EditText`'s gravity programmatically, in your code. That is, after `setContentView()`, use `findViewById()` to get the `EditText`, then call `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)` on it.

Answer (score 11):

In Android, we can set gravity both programmatically and in XML.
To set edit text hint in the center see the code below in which I use `android:gravity="center"` in XML.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:hint="Email" />
```

**For showing the hint at top|left and the text typed in edit text to be at center** or to set different gravity for TextInputLayout's hint and text in Android, you need to try the code below.

In .xml you need to set EditText's hint gravity `top|left`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And in your java (activity) file, set EditText's text gravity center programmatically:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

See the screenshot with the result:

[image]

Comment: please read the question in want to set different gravity for hint of the edit text and the text which is being typed

Comment: hello @sharath please show my edited answer. It will help you.

Comment: @sharath can you try this??

Comment: Hello @sharath my code is useful to you?? If yes then accept my answer and if you have any query feel free to ask me

Comment: Work for Material's `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` in July 2019 as well

Answer (score 1):

Different gravity works `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` and below version but does not work in `1.2.0` or above.
To make it work in `1.1.0` or below follow these steps.

1. set `TextInputEditText` gravity to start in xml

   `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText id="@+id/text" gravity="start"/>`
2. then programmatically set its gravity to center

   `text.gravity=Gravity.CENTER`